# ThreadAbortException when Task calls method in service reference

Tags: c#, .net, service, task, threadabortexception

I need to call a method in a Service Reference with the name CancelTransactionByRefPos.
This method has the following signature:

```
int CancelTransactionByRefPos(long refPos, out string resultDescription);
```

If this method returns '0' the cancel is succeeded. If this method returns another value, the method has to be called again.

I have written a Cancel method which calls the CancelTransactionByRefPos. It is very important the call happens asynchronous because it can take 30 seconds till a response is given.

My method looks like:

```
public void Cancel(long refPos, GiftCard giftCard, Account_3_2 account)
    {
       var task =  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int result;
            do
            {
                string resultDescription;
                result = _client.CancelTransactionByRefPos(refPos, out resultDescription);
                // logic to log the result with the giftcard and account parameter
            } while (result != 0);
        });
        // task.Wait(); // ######## Uncomment this -> code executes! ######## 
    }
```

When I Cancel with the task.Wait() part in comment, I get a ThreadAbortException.

When I uncomment the task.Wait() and execute again, everything is doing well but if I have to wait until my task is executed, there is no use calling the method asynchronous.

**EDIT**

I have also configurated the service reference so it allows generation of asynchronous operations. Same problem.

Comment: I'm thinking about the problem; however, just an aside, what if you make the caller of your Cancel() call that method asynchronously instead of making the asynchronous call inside of your Cancel() method?  (That seems more logical to me.)

Comment: Hi, Markus.
I found out what the problem is. If my main thread ends, all running tasks are aborted. I had a short running main thread because the cancel method was called from unit test methods. 

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Sweet! Glad you figured it out.